# How can I track which page is being requested using multiple VirtualHost in Apache?

Tags: network-traffic, apache-1.3, web-server

I have an Apache 1.3 web server configured with several `VirtualHost` entries that serves multiple independent websites.

At certain times Apache receives a huge amount of request, which causes the server to reach a high workload. I would like to know which of all of these sites are receiving the requests.

How can I do that? I have read about [Apache's `mod_info` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_info.html), but I do not know if it has security risks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one log file for each domain e.g. /var/log/apache/domain.tld/access_log

Then you could use watch, sort and du to find out which file changes most rapidly (as apache always adds things to logfiles)

```
# watch "du -k /var/log/apache/*/access_log |sort -n"
```

Or if you have  a lot of files and you are only interested in thost changing the most

```
# watch "du -k /var/log/apache/*/access_log |sort -n |tail -30"
```

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to alter your `LogFormat` to include `%v`, which is the `ServerName` of the `<VirtualHost>` serving the request.

From there, analysis of the logs will allow you to determine where the majority of the requests are coming in to.

Comment: In this particular case I already have a separated log for each site. But it's a nice alternative too

Answer (score 0):

You can log the hostname requested with:

```
%{Host}i
```

You can log the ServerName of the VirtualHost with:

```
%v
```